# Discord.js bots: organizing commands

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Hi i was making my first bot using discord.js and i noticed after added few commands that my commands folder will get flooded easily I'm using a simple command handler from Discord.js Guide https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/ however i'll need slot of files just to make simple commands ii wanted to ask people who already had experience in this stuff on how to organize my commands

Answer (score 1):

If you want to better organize your command files, you can separate the commands with categories and then create a folder for each category inside the commands folder.

for example:

```
commands
 ┣ moderation
 ┗ fun
```

After that you can loop through each of these new folders and load the command files inside them the same way you've done with your command handler

```js
// First get the category directories
const isDirectory = source => fs.lstatSync(source).isDirectory();
const getDirectories = source => fs.readdirSync(source).map(name => join(source, name)).filter(isDirectory);

// Then load the commands
getDirectories(__dirname + '/commands').forEach(category => {
  const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(category).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

  for(const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./${category}/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for answering! but after added that code in the bot's main file and after adding categorys and stuff i get this error 
`const getDirectories = source => fs.readdirSync(source).map(name => join(source, name)).filter(isDirectory);
                                                                    ^

ReferenceError: join is not defined`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/d9z0t2Sa full code of the main file

Comment: Oh my bad, you should have `const path = require('path');` and change `join(source, name)` to `path.join(source, name)`

Comment: now it gives me error `Error: Cannot find module './C:\Users\Aoshey\Desktop\Taco Bot\commands\economy/balance.js'` even tho that "balance.js" already exists https://imgur.com/a/3WTKOXB