# Organize command files

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have [this code excerpt from Vinicius Antonio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65703794/16214137):

```
// First get the category directories
const isDirectory = source => fs.lstatSync(source).isDirectory();
const getDirectories = source => fs.readdirSync(source).map(name => join(source, name)).filter(isDirectory);

// Then load the commands
getDirectories(__dirname + '/commands').forEach(category => {
  const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(category).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

  for(const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./${category}/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
  }
});
```

Only then comes this:

> const getDirectories = source => fs.readdirSync(source).map(name => join(source, name)).filter(isDirectory);
> ^
> ReferenceError: join is not defined

I already have the rest of the code to make the bot work at all!

Comment: Where is `join` defined?

Comment: Didn't specify Vinicius Antonio!

Comment: I think `join` comes from importing [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths)

Comment: Hmm ... And how do I declare that?

Comment: `const { join } = require('path');`? https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8/